# Leaflet/MarkerCluster plugin - how do update the HTML content of a DivIcon?

Tags: leaflet, clustering

In Leaflet, I am using the markercluster plugin, in which you can use the DivIcon class to display custom icons for the clusters. You can set your own HTML for these clusters. However, I can't find how to update the HTML of an existing cluster icon. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use setIcon like that

```
var img2 = "<img src='image.jpg' />";
var icon2 = L.divIcon({
        html: img2,
        // Specify a class name we can refer to in CSS.
        className: 'image-icon',
        // Set a markers width and height.
        iconSize: [52, 52]
        });


marker.setIcon(icon2);
```

Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/n53nhu9e/)